# Indistinguishable objects in the category of graphs

Tags: graph-theory, ct.category-theory

I was thinking about this question a couple of days ago, and got reminded again by a recent question on graph homomorphisms.

Given a graph $G$, we call two vertices $u,v$ indistinguishable if the map which interchanges $u$ and $v$ and is the identity on the rest of the vertices is an isomorphism. Let $\mathbb{Graph}$ be the underlying quiver of the category of graphs with graph homomorphisms. I.e. the vertices are isomorphism classes of finite graphs, and there are $|Hom(G,H)|$ arrows from $G$ to $H$.

Is it true that $\mathbb{Graph}$ has no pairs of indistinguishable vetices?

Comment: @Tom: Sorry, I meant to ask a simpler question and Chris Godsil below guessed correctly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's an old result of Lovasz that if $|\mathrm{Hom}(G,X)|=|\mathrm{Hom}(H,X)|$ for all graphs $X$, then $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic. If I understand your quiver correctly, the answer to your question is yes, for the trivial reason that the quiver does not contain a pair of equivalent vertices.

Comment: Ok, yes, that is the question I meant to ask. What is Lovasz' paper where he proves this?

Comment: It might be in L. Lov ́asz: Direct product in locally finite categories, Acta Sci. Math. Szeged 23 (1972),
319-322. (But it's not that hard to prove.)

Comment: The discussion in http://www.cs.elte.hu/~lovasz/hom-survey.pdf seems to imply than an extra technical condition ("twin-freeness") is required. Is this satisfied by the questioner's setup? I can't tell.